# SnakeYAML don't repeat keys

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

How can I configure SnakeYAML DumperOptions to do this:

```
key:
  value1: 3
  value2: 5
```

instead of this:

```
key.value1: 3
key.value2: 5
```

?

Comment: To me, it at least *looks* like that it is outputting the file as a `properties` file instead of YAML.

Comment: But could you show the code responsible for producing the output you are currently getting?

Comment: I'm using this library: https://github.com/SpongePowered/Configurate

Comment: The two files are not equivalent. `key.value1` is a *single* scalar in YAML, not some short form of nested mappings. SnakeYAML will never produce one layout when your data matches the other. You need to show us what you're doing in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my problem was that "key.value1" was the actual key, including the dot.